# PostMessage() in C# post WM_LBUTTONDOWN message to annothor applycation It doesn't work

Tags: c#, sendmessage, postmessage

```
        IntPtr windowHandle = FindWindow(null,"Wpf");
        PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, (280 << 16) | 280);
        PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, (280 << 16) | 280);
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
```

another app

```
    public void ReceiveOneStone(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HIT ME");
    }

    Stone = new Ellipse();
    Stone.MouseLeftButtonDown += ReceiveOneStone
```

I have check the Handle is correct.

And use spy++ to find that the other application had receive the the exactly the same WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP message as I use the mouse to click at the pos to get .

But the application doesn't respond when I PostMessage to it.

PS : I have used mouse_event to achieve the effect as the real mouse click.

But it cannot be effective when the desired window had been blocked by some other window.(overlapped)

I have tried in another way that I let the mouse stay in the desire the window and press ENTER to make my former application to send a WM_LBUTTONDOWN message and IT WORKS.

Is there any other message I should send to ACHIEVE the goal.

Will someone teach me how to use SendMessage or PostMessage to achive the goal

Comment: Can you state, succinctly, what the overall goal *is*? I presume it's more than just "send two windows messages to another window" - is it something along the lines of attempting to *control* the other application? If so, maybe look into [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes.But UI elements of the other application are unknown to me.I'm not the writer of the other application.What I write above is just a demo.

Comment: UI automation (that I linked to) is the tool that's used for e.g. accessibility tools such as screen readers or alternative input systems. Trust me, those tools aren't written against the specifics of the applications they're working against.

Comment: Are you positive that your x, y coordinates are correct? If you listen to the program's messages as you click it normally with spy++ do the messages tell you the button is around (280, 280)?